# rails: display errors for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where a user can create multiple records at the same time, so my controller action looks like this:

```
  if Unit.create multiple_unit_params.values
    redirect_to units_path
  else
    render :new
  end
```

The validation can fail for any one of the records. So how am I supposed to render errors in the view if I don't know what record validation failed since there are multiple records?

Answer (score 0):

One way to conquer this is to use the `create!` method that raises exceptions. The exception object contains information on the model that failed.

The pattern I tend to use looks like this:

```
def create
  @unit = Unit.new(multiple_unit_params.values)

  @unit.save!

  redirect_to(units_path)

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  # ... Deal with exception
end
```

If you're creating multiple records you may want to encapsulate that in a transaction so you don't end up with some created, some uncreated. It'll be an all-or-none thing. Exceptions automatically unwind transactions.